# Odoo: custom context in act_window + refresh issue

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

I am really stucked with that one.
I am on Odoo 11.

Here is what I want to achieve:

1. I want to add a custom default search filter in customer kanban/tree view
2. This filter depends on user's company_id
   it looks like this (in python)

`{'search_default_incompany_ids': self.env.user.company_id.name}`

Here is what I do :

**OPTION 1:**

At first I thought to just replace the "context" in the existing Customer "act_window" :
In my view :

```
<record id="base.action_partner_form" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="context">{"search_default_customer":1, 'search_default_incompany_ids': user.company_id.name}</field>
    </record>
```

=> I tried with "user.company_id.name" or "company_id.name" or many things but no way to access user or company_id in this xml...

=> i can only access "uid" which i don't think is enough to get back to 'company_id' in xml (?)

So i went for a python solution :

**OPTION 2:**

In the menuitem, i redefine the action, and use an action server, itself calling python code :
Menuitem

```
<menuitem id="sale.res_partner_menu"
              parent="sale.sale_order_menu"
              action="action_partner_form_custom_multicompany"
              sequence="3" groups="sales_team.group_sale_salesman"/>
```

Action server :

```
<record id="action_partner_form_custom_multicompany" model="ir.actions.server">
        <field name="name">Customers</field>
        <field name="condition">True</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_res_partner"/>
        <field name="state">code</field>
        <field name="code">action = model.list_all_customers()</field>
    </record>
```

And python :

```
@api.model
def list_all_customers(self):
    context = {"search_default_customer": 1}
    if self.env.user.company_id:
        context.update({'search_default_incompany_ids': self.env.user.company_id.name})

    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_model': 'res.partner',
        'name': "Customers",
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'kanban,tree,form',
        'target': 'current',
        'context': context,
    }
```

=> Now this works fine in displaying kanban/tree view with the default search filter I want. This is exactly what I want so far....

**BUT, now from the kanban/tree, if I open a record, the form opens, and.. if I refresh the form page : it goes back to kanban/list ! This is my problem !**

Of course, this was not the behaviour with the native menuitem + act_window.

What am I missing ?

**EDIT :**

I noticed that in form the url looks like this : web#id=20105&view_type=form&model=res.partner&menu_id=98 => there is no "action" like it is in e.g. sale order : web#id=28&view_type=form&model=sale.order&menu_id=237&action=317 This is probably due to the fact that the action used is in python and not stored in DB... Is there a way around this ?

Thank you for your help !

AD

Comment: I also tried to call the existing act_window from python, update its context, and return it (I was thinking I missed some data in context dict) but this did not fix the problem..

Comment: I noticed that in form the url looks like this :
web#id=20105&view_type=form&model=res.partner&menu_id=98

=> there is no "action" like it is in e.g. sale order :
web#id=28&view_type=form&model=sale.order&menu_id=237&action=317

This is probably due to the fact that the action used is in python and not stored in DB...

Is there a way around this ?